# Concatenate and Remove spaces from 4 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I need to output 1 column that contains all possible combinations of strings from 4 columns, concatenated and with spaces removed using T-SQL query or Excel formula.

**Details:**
I have a table with 4 rows and 4 columns filled with various strings of different lengths.  I need to output the all possible combinations of strings in each column.  Because I have a 4x4 table, I am expecting 256 different combinations.

Luckily, I can do this with this SQL query:

```
select
    t1.A,
    t2.B,
    t3.C,
    t4.D
from 
    table t1 cross join
    table t2 cross join
    table t3 cross join
    table t4
```

However, this gives me an out put with 4 columns.  I need concatenate the results and remove any spaces.

For now, I use the SQL query above, then copy and paste the results into Excel.  From Excel, I would use the TRIM and CONCATENATE functions to get a single column of what I need.

Is there a simple way to do this with a T-SQL query?
Better yet, is there an Excel formula I can use to do this?

I have an Excel formula I use, but it only works for 2 columns.  Once I get the combinations from the 2 columns, I copy and paste to another sheet, enter the values of the 3rd column into the new sheet and use the same formula.  Not sure how to extend this to 4 columns.

```
IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/COUNTA(B:B)+1))&INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1))
```

Edit:
Example Table:

```
A  B  C  D
-----------
01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08
09 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Desired Results:

```
Results
--------
01020304
01020308
01020312
01020316
........
13141512
13141516
```

Comment: As TRIM (with CONCATENATE) removes the spaces only between concatenated strings, do not you need also a method for removing mid-string spaces?

Comment: Spaces mid-string are fine, just the spaces around them.  For example, if one of the string was " Get Ready ", I just need it to show "Get Ready".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(A.col1)),RTRIM(LTRIM(B.col2)),RTRIM(LTRIM(C.col3)),RTRIM(LTRIM(D.col4)))
FROM        yourTable A
CROSS JOIN  yourTable B
CROSS JOIN  yourTable C
CROSS JOIN  yourTable D
```

Comment: The first part of the code requires entry of string?  How would I get the strings from an existing table with strings?

Comment: Are you talking about how I create #yourTable?

Comment: The code above works great! But since I already have the 4x4 table stored in my database, is there a way for me to avoid entering these values?

Comment: Sorry, you must be new to this. I use my #yourTable to create a sample table. You don't actually use it. It's only for demonstrative purposes. You take my select statement and change #yourTable to your table name and change the column names to the column names from your table.